# Treating 'master' and 'refs/heads/master' as the same branch in TeamCity

Tags: git, github, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

Working with github and teamcity, builds seem to either be `refs/heads/master` or `master` branch.

Whenever the github service hook launches a build, it is on the branch `master`.

Whenever TeamCity launches a build (e.g. when I start a build, or a dependency building triggers a build) the branch is `refs/heads/master`.

This causes two build numbers to be shown on the same page, the last build for `master` and the last build for `refs/heads/master`.

Is there a way to make TeamCity triggered builds build `master` instead of `refs/heads/master`?

Or is there a way to get `master` and `refs/heads/master` to be treated as the same branch, not as different ones?

Comment: would "Branch label on a build" mentioned in http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/What's+New+in+TeamCity+7.1 help in any way?

Comment: I looked at that, and tried adding `+:refs/heads/(master)` to the branch specification. Unfortunately that just made it show two 'master' branches, instead of combining them.

Comment: I think that may have actually worked, I had to do a few other things as well, and delete all old builds, but that helped @VonC

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think I found a solution to this, though it isn't ideal because I had to delete all passed builds.

I had to first copy the projects and delete the old ones to get rid of all builds that had been run.

Then I configured the default branch to be `master`. And I set the other branch specifications to:

```
+:(master)
+:refs/heads/(master)
```

Also, I updated the VSC trigger to listen on `+:master` instead of `+:*`.

Then I tested by manually triggering a build, and having github test hook trigger a build. It seem to have worked, they are both grouped under `master`!

Comment: It worked fine without `+:(master)`. I set default branch to `master` and added `+:refs/heads/(master)` to other branch specification. (TeamCity 8.1.5)

Comment: This answer was really helpful. I'd like to add that you can add format like so: `+:refs/heads/(release/*) ` this way in TC you see `release/1.0`

Comment: The explanation from JetBrains for why this is necessary is here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-51478 -- I feel like this deserves some more explicit documentation though...